Storing an array of strings
how to modify the following code so that one can use \mydata{one,two,three} and \mydata[1] instead of \storedata\mydata{{one}{two}{three}} and \getdata[1]\mydata  ?  original link : Storing an array of strings in a command

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcount\tmpnum
\def\storedata#1#2{\tmpnum=0 \edef\tmp{\string#1}\storedataA#2\end}
\def\storedataA#1{\advance\tmpnum by1
   \ifx\end#1\else
      \expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\the\tmpnum\endcsname{#1}%
      \expandafter\storedataA\fi
}
\def\getdata[#1]#2{\csname data:\string#2:#1\endcsname}

\storedata\mydata{{one}{two}{three}}

A:\getdata[1]\mydata   % returns one
B:\getdata[2]\mydata   % returns two
C:\getdata[3]\mydata   % returns three

\end{document}



This is a horrible user interface - why do it?

just curious. I would't use it.

The syntax is awful and has the big disadvantage of not being expandable.
You can't have \mydata{<whatever>} unless you previously tell TeX that \mydata has some definition and you apparently want that the first occurrence populates the array.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\arraydefine}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
   {
    \xcn_array_define:n {##1}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_array_define:n
 {
  % first define the cs to populate the array
  \clist_new:c { l_xcn_array_#1_clist }
  \cs_if_free:cTF {#1}
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn {#1} ##1
     {
      \clist_set:cn { l_xcn_array_#1_clist } {##1}
      \cs_gset:cpn {#1} ####1 { \__xcn_arrayuse:nn {#1} {####1} }
     }
   }
   {\ERROR}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__xcn_arrayuse:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
   {% empty argument, return the length
    \clist_count:c { l_xcn_array_#1_clist }
   }
   {% nonempty argument, return the item
    \clist_item:cn { l_xcn_array_#1_clist } {#2}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\arraydefine{mydata,another,box}

\mydata{one,two,three}
\another{A,B,C,D}

\begin{document}

\mydata{1} and \mydata{}

\another{4} and \another{}

\end{document}


Add yourself the check that the required item is actually available in the array. The check that the macro is available will raise \ERROR, fix it to give a more meaningful message.
I simply wouldn't do it like this. The syntax with \storedata and \getdata is much clearer.

This is pretty non-standard syntax, and you shouldn't use this. That doesn't mean it's not possible though (just not in an expandable manner). The following implements it (but, imho, don't use this):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\NewMyArray{m}
  {
    \seq_new:c { l__xcn_array_values_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
    \NewDocumentCommand#1{o g}
      {
        \IfNoValueTF {##1}
          {
            \IfNoValueTF {##2}
              { \msg_error:nnn { xcn } { misused-array } {#1} }
              {
                \seq_set_from_clist:cn
                  { l__xcn_array_values_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
                  {##2}
              }
          }
          {
            \IfNoValueTF {##2}
              {
                \seq_item:cn
                  { l__xcn_array_values_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
                  {##1}
              }
              { \msg_error:nnn { xcn } { misused-array } {#1} }
          }
      }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { xcn } { misused-array }
  {
    Misused~ array~ #1~ encountered.~
    Either~ use~ as~ #1[<item>]~ or~ as~ #1{<values>}.
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewMyArray\mydata
\mydata{one,two,three}

\begin{document}

A:\mydata[1]   % returns one
B:\mydata[2]   % returns two
C:\mydata[3]   % returns three

\end{document}


Here is OpTeX's solution. \decldata\foo declares an expandable macro \foo which is able to set data by \foo{one,two,three} and get data by \foo[2].
\def\getdata#1[#2]{\cs{data:#1[#2]}}
\def\setdata#1#2{\ima\tmpnum=0
   \foreach#2,\do##1,{\ima\incr\tmpnum \ima\sdef{data:#1[\the\tmpnum]}{##1}}}
\let\ima=\immediateassignment

\def\decldata#1{\ea\decldataA\ea{\csstring#1}#1}
\def\decldataA#1#2{\ifx#2\undefined 
      \def#2{\isnextchar\bgroup{\setdata{#1}}{\isnextchar[{\getdata{#1}}{}}}
   \else \opwarning{\string\decldata\string#2 ignored. \string#2 is defined already}\fi
}

\decldata\mydata \decldata\another \decldata\box

\mydata{one,two,three}

\mydata[2] % prints two

\another{U,V,W,X,Y,Z}

\another[2] % prints V
\another[5] % prints Y

\bye

